# Connect VirtualBox to a different internet connection

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ethernet, network-adapter, usb-network-adapter

At the moment, I have my host machine setup to access the internet using the main ethernet connection via a NIC.

I have a VM which currently has it's network settings set to NAT, this allows the guest machine to connect to the internet using the same connection as the host machine.

I have a usb internet connection.  If the host machine has both the ethernet connection and usb internet connection attached, how do I set things up so the host machine uses the ethernet connection to gain access to the internet and the guest machine uses the usb connection to gain access to the internet?

```
Host machine = Windows XP
Guest machine = Ubuntu 10.04
```

These are the 2 connections I currently have:

[image]

From these 2 connections, the wireless connection is my main host pc connection which at the moment both host and guest machines use.  I want to continue using the wireless connection on the host pc, but on the virtual machine guest pc, I want to use the wired connection 2.  The wired conneciton 2 is the usb connection.

What I don't understand is what am I supposed to do on the following screen in virtualbox to select the wired connection 2?:

[image]

Comment: I've added further details with images to explain the problem further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the VM's network interface to bridge mode. This will allow you to select which network interface you want to use.

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#idp19241824

Answer (score 3):

In you host PC, open the USB network adapter property, uncheck the IPV4 and IPV6, so this adapter does not get any IP. In your VM settings, chose the USB adapter.

Comment: I've added further details with images to explain the problem further.

Answer (score 1):

virtualbox allows  make as many network connections as you want. you could just add a *new* one on setting page i.e. eth0, eth1, eth2 ... in guest mashine make *ifup*. it seems that i advice you the same thst garconcn do

Comment: I've added further details with images to explain the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

Tell VirtualBox you want to have access to the USB device. Once your operating systems can detect the hardware install the drivers for it. Once you do that disable the original network device and use the USB device instead.

Comment: I've added further details with images to explain the problem further.

Comment: My advice reamins the same.  Disable all other internet devices on the virtual machine, attach the usb device, and setup an internet connection once the device is detected.  I hope you didn't downvote my answer....